# Magento 2 Default Meta description has no effect

Tags: theme, seo, meta-description

I try to add meta description to my Magento 2 theme under **Content -> Design -> configuration -> Edit -> HTML Head -> default meta description**

but the text I add has no effect, when I look at the source code,
`<meta name="description" content="">` just show something completely different, which I have no idea where the text come from.

Am I misunderstanding how Magento 2 meta description works?

Comment: Did you clear the cache?

Comment: Also what page are you on? Homepage? Or something else.

Comment: @AdarshKhatri Yes I cleared cache.

Comment: @DominicXigen it's home page

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It works for me on the path you shared. Try clearing cache and browser. You may also have a look at content > pages > home or homepage... there will be meta description fields as well.

Comment: You are right, in my case it was the meta description from Content -> Pages -> Home that override the text from Content -> Design -> configuration -> Edit -> HTML Head -> default meta description.